# PHP: using cookies within PHP in a noJS site

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to create a class for using cookies, but for some reason when I try to register a cookie with the browser (using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m), it does not work.

I cannot understand what the issue is as; I can register the cookie (and see it in the browser) but when I use the `retrieveCookie($name)` function, it doesn't work.

The PHP class is as follows:

```
<?php
class cookies
{
    public function __construct() {  }

    /**
     * Register a cookie with the browser.
     * @param string $name Name to be given to the cookie
     * @param string $value Value to be put inside the cookie
     * @param int $expire How long the cookie will last, leave at 0 to expire on end of session/when the browser closes
     * @return bool True if cookie is created and false if not
     */
    public function registerCookie($name, $value = '', $expire = 0)
    {
        return setcookie($name, $value, $expire);
    }

    /**
     * Summary of retrieveCookie
     * @param string $name The name of the cookie to retrieve
     * @return bool True if found/not empty and false if not
     */
    public function retrieveCookie($name)
    {
        $return = true;
        isset($_COOKIE[$name]) ?: $return = false;
        !empty($_COOKIE[$name]) ?: $return = false;
        return $return ? $_COOKIE[$name] : $return;
    }
}
```

Calling the class as such:

```
$cookie = new cookies();
$cookie->registerCookie("myName", "Sam", 0);
var_dump($cookie->retrieveCookie("myName"));
```

Can anyone help me here? Is my validation wrong for example?

Comment: The cookie won't be available until the next request.

Comment: @JonStirling, what do you mean? (You'll have to forgive my lack of knowledge, I am unsure of what I am doing with cookies as yet)

Comment: $_COOKIE is populated from the client request. When using setcookie, a cookie is sent with the response. Therefore, your new cookie won't exist in $_COOKIE until, 1)  you've sent the cookie, 2) the client makes a new request which include the new cookie you've set.

Comment: @JonStirling, that makes sense, thank you for clarifying this for me :)